# Modbus RTU for FPGA

Tags: fpga, modbus

I need to implement Modbus RTU in FPGA (Cyclone 3). Basically I see two ways to do that. The first one is to hardcode it in VHDL and it doesn't seem to be that hard at the begining. But I have looked through internet and somewhy have found no examples at all of such an approach. The second way is to softcode it in NIOS2. It seems to be harder, but it looks like it's more popular. So which way is actually more simple? (I can stick to a fixed ID and all UART configurations)

Comment: Modbus is usually implemented on top of a standard asynchronous serial protocol. Why not to go the same way? Implement hardware UART, then implement Modbus on top of it in software.

Comment: UART might also be hard- or softcoded, so it is not the problem. Besides there is a pretty simple IP core in Qsys. But what about modbus?

Comment: Do you need master or slave?

Comment: I need to design the slave part